# How to access a variable set within an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, var

I'm trying to set a variable within a function that calls some PHP code via Ajax. The problem is that the variable is not accessible from outside the function, so to say.

```
var startPageSelected = '';

function getSavedStartPage() {
    $.post(webroot + 'home/get_saved_startpage/',
    function(data){
        startPageSelected = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(startPageSelected); //alert 1
    });
}

function something() {
    alert(startPageSelected); //alert 2
}
```

So when I call **getSavedStartPage** the "**alert 1**" gives me the correct value, but outside of this like "**alert 2**" in my example, the variable remains empty. I guess it has something to do with the scope and/or the asynchronous ajax stuff but I couldn't figure out how to store my ajax data instead so that I can access it from outside later on. Maybe someone can help me on that?

Comment: I don't think it's *not accessible* due to scope, you are probably just calling something() before the AJAX call completes and before the variable is set

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your retured data as a parameter to your function.

```
function getSavedStartPage() {
    $.post(webroot + 'home/get_saved_startpage/',
    function(data){
        startPageSelected = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(startPageSelected); //alert 1
        something(startPageSelected);
    });
}

function something(data) {
    alert(data); //alert 2
}
```