# Javascript ajax post, how to get variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access a variable set within an Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820902/how-to-access-a-variable-set-within-an-ajax-call)

I am struggling a little, I have a ajax post, and I get a number returned from the call.
My question is, how do I get the result number into a variables that can be seen outside the `$.post` call ?

E.g:

```
 //code here

    $.post('../utility/width.php', { adress:adr } , 
            function(width) {
            //this width result, I want it to be used
            });
         // here
         //code here
```

Comment: You have to call a function inside the callback and pass the value to it.

Comment: If you can't do it with another function/callback you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous. You'll have to use a callback function that gets called when the AJAX request finishes:

```
$.post('../utility/width.php',
    {adress:adr},
    function(width) {
        alert(width);
    }
});
```

An alternative would be to make the request synchronous, but that probably isn't something you want.